# No suitable image found Python

Tags: python, python-import

Kind of a noob when it comes to dealing with python errors. I'm trying to import scipy library and i get:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.cpython-35m-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the code that's generating the error? Please, show your work.

Comment: Also, what did google tell you when you searched this error?

Comment: did you find a solution or hints ?